# Visualize matrix with different values as colours in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, heatmap

I just would like to print a matrix with three different values (e.g. 0,1, and 2) as different colours.
Imagine I have the following grid

```
import numpy as np
grid=np.zeros((5, 5))
grid[1][1]=2
grid[3][8]=2
grid[3][4]=1
grid[6][7]=1
grid[7][7]=1
```

How can I visualize it in a way that I have like a board and I highlight with a colour the positions where I have value "1" and with another colour the position where I have value "2".

I tried with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax=plt.subplots
ax.imshow(grid)
```

But I get the error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'imshow'"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You forgot the `()` after plt.subplots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
grid=np.zeros((9, 9))
grid[1][1]=2
grid[3][8]=2
grid[3][4]=1
grid[6][7]=1
grid[7][7]=1

plt.imshow(grid)
```

[image]

Note you were trying to set an element outside your defined array in your example. So I expanded the definition to size `(9,9)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
_, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(grid)
```